closing one indicator when another has triggered
I have written this code after combining 2 indicators. They seem to draw correctly individually, but when combined, the "stoch entry" label remains. I'm not sure if it's a repainting issue or coding.
I wanted the plot shape of pivot Ready to remain, but if stochastic was first to trade disable the Pivot or if pivot first to trade to disable stoch trade
traded_today        = false
traded_today1      = false
stop_pivot          = false
stop_stoch          = false
var longOn         = false



trade_Pivot  = input.bool(false, "turn Pivot trading On", group=g_4, inline="", tooltip="turn Pivot trading On")
trade_Stoch  = input.bool(false, "turn Stoch roll over On", group=g_4, inline="", tooltip="turn Stoch Roll over On")
//pivot_buy
pivot_buy = open >= vPP and close < vPPenter image description here

//stoch
cond2_long = ta.crossover(k,d)  and k < stochOS and barstate.isconfirmed

// // Pivots
if newDay and open > vPP 
    startAboveP := true

▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲                                                                  
//                                          -   TRADE CONDITIONS   -                                                      
// ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼

//Pivots
Pivot_Ready  = not traded_today and  startAboveP and trade_Pivot

Pivot_Entry = not traded_today1 and pivot_buy and not stop_pivot and trade_Pivot

//stoch
validLong = not longOn and cond2_long and not stop_stoch and trade_Stoch


▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲                                                                  
//                                          -   ALERTS FUNCTIONS   -                                                      
// ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
if Pivot_Ready
    traded_today := true

// Pivot
    
if Pivot_Entry
    traded_today1   := true
    stop_stoch      := true
    alert("Buy "  + syminfo.ticker + " at " + str.tostring(vPP, format.mintick) +  "\n TP1 " + str.tostring(vR1, format.mintick) + "\n SL " + str.tostring(vS1, format.mintick) + "\n Pivot_Buy" + "\n\n Time Stamp of trigger\n" + "\n\n Time of trade " + str.tostring(t) , alert.freq_once_per_bar)
 
// Stoch
if validLong
    longOn      := true
    stop_pivot  := true
    longSL  := close - i_Stop_Loss   * 10 * syminfo.mintick
    longTP  := close + i_Take_Profit * 10 * syminfo.mintick
    alert("Buy " + syminfo.ticker + " at " + str.tostring(close, format.mintick) + "\n TP1 " + str.tostring(longTP, format.mintick) + "\n SL " + str.tostring(longSL, format.mintick) + "\n Stoch" + "\n\n Time Stamp of trigger\n" + "\n\n Time of trade " + str.tostring(barTimeFormatted) , alert.freq_once_per_bar) 
 
// TRADES SHAPES
plotshape(Pivot_Ready  , title="Pivot_Ready" , text="Pivot\nsetup "  , color=color.rgb(34, 185, 39), style=shape.labeldown  , location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.rgb(0, 0, 0))//lotshape(shortReady , title="Pivot_Sell", text="Sell\nReady" , color=color.rgb(185, 37, 34), style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.rgb(0, 0, 0))

plotshape(Pivot_Entry  , title="Pivot_Entry" , text="Pivot Buy "  , color=color.rgb(34, 185, 39), style=shape.labelup  , location = location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.rgb(0, 0, 0))//lotshape(shortReady , title="Pivot_Sell", text="Sell\nReady" , color=color.rgb(185, 37, 34), style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.rgb(0, 0, 0))


//stoch
plotshape(validLong , title="Stoch_Buy" , text="Stoch_Buy"  , color=color.rgb(34, 185, 39), style=shape.labelup  , location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.black)




Don't forget to include subjects when you write sentences in English.

It might be because the validLong condition remains true. You might want to add a check for stop_stoch in your plotshape function for the Stochastic Buy like so:
plotshape(validLong and not stop_stoch, title="Stoch_Buy" , text="Stoch_Buy"  , color=color.rgb(34, 185, 39), style=shape.labelup  , location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.black)

This way, the Stochastic Buy label will only be plotted if validLong is true and stop_stoch is false, meaning no Pivot trade has occurred yet. You can do a similar thing for the Pivot Entry label.
Remember to reset your stop_stoch and stop_pivot variables to false at the start of a new trading day or whenever you want your indicators to be able to trigger again.
